# FosMessageBundle sendId cannot be null

Tags: php, symfony, message-bundle

I implemented fosMessageBundle with my message bundle, but if I want send a new message use fos_message.composer ,I got this error:

```
    An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO Message (body, created_at, threadId,   sendId) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["Test mesaj\u0131", "2013-12-23 12:15:48", 32, null]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'sendId' cannot be null
```

---

my question is, why message bundle not set send id ?

---

note : I was debugging setSender datas. every data seems is ok.

---

Codes :

```
$sender     = $this->getUser();
        $threadBuilder = $this->get('fos_message.composer')->newThread();
        $threadBuilder->
            addRecipient($clinicOwner)
            ->setSender($sender)
            ->setSubject($form['subject'])
            ->setBody($form['message']);
        $sender = $this->get('fos_message.sender');
        $sender->send($threadBuilder->getMessage());
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

manyToOne.sender.joinColumn.name in message.orm.yml is wrong writed.

wrong :

```
manyToOne:
thread:
  targetEntity: ATL\MessageBundle\Entity\Thread
  inversedBy: messages
  joinColumn:
    name: threadId
    referencedColumnName: id
sender:
  targetEntity: ATL\UserBundle\Entity\User
  joinColumn:
    name: **threadId**
    referencedColumnName: id
```

true:

```
manyToOne:
thread:
  targetEntity: ATL\MessageBundle\Entity\Thread
  inversedBy: messages
  joinColumn:
    name: threadId
    referencedColumnName: id
sender:
  targetEntity: ATL\UserBundle\Entity\User
  joinColumn:
    name: sendId
    referencedColumnName: id
```